# Apache Isis: How to get the value of the added custom wicket component

Tags: java, wicket, isis

I'm quite new to Apache ISIS, and I'm trying to add a custom wicket component by extending `ScalarPanelAbstract`.

I have a method accepting a `pageable` parameter. The `pageable` is an interface that consists **Page number** and **Page size**.

```
//region > findAllWithPage (action)
    @Action(semantics = SemanticsOf.SAFE)
    public PagedList<Employee> findAllWithPage(
            @Parameter(optionality = Optionality.OPTIONAL)
            final Pageable pageable) {

        return employeeRepository.findByOwner(userTenancyService.owner(), pageable);
    }
//endregion
```

This is what it looks like when you use the action [`findAllWithPage`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqzIt.png). It only has one argument which is the pageable.

---

Now, what I'm trying to do is to make it accept two arguments, [`Page number` and `Page size`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryUA5.png).

My problem is, I could not get the the value of the two textfields. This is the error that I got.

```html
org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: Method onRequest of interface org.apache.wicket.behavior.IBehaviorListener targeted at org.apache.wicket.ajax.markup.html.form.AjaxButton$1@c6dc7e3 on component [AjaxButton [Component id = okButton]] threw an exception
 at org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface.internalInvoke(RequestListenerInterface.java:268)
 at org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface.invoke(RequestListenerInterface.java:241)
 at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.invokeListener(ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.java:250)
 at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.respond(ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.java:236)
 at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle$HandlerExecutor.respond(RequestCycle.java:890)
 at org.apache.wicket.request.RequestHandlerStack.execute(RequestHandlerStack.java:64)
 at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.execute(RequestCycle.java:261)
 at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequest(RequestCycle.java:218)
 at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequestAndDetach(RequestCycle.java:289)
 at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequestCycle(WicketFilter.java:259)
 at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequest(WicketFilter.java:201)
 at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketServlet.doPost(WicketServlet.java:159)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:821)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1685)
 at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449)
 at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365)
 at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
 at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
 at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:383)
 at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362)
 at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1668)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:581)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1158)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:511)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1090)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:119)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:517)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:308)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:242)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:261)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:75)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceAndRun(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:213)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:147)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:654)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:572)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
 at org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface.internalInvoke(RequestListenerInterface.java:258)
 ... 44 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
 at org.apache.isis.core.metamodel.facets.actions.action.invocation.ActionInvocationFacetForDomainEventAbstract.invokeMethodElseFromCache(ActionInvocationFacetForDomainEventAbstract.java:408)
 at org.apache.isis.core.metamodel.facets.actions.action.invocation.ActionInvocationFacetForDomainEventAbstract$2.execute(ActionInvocationFacetForDomainEventAbstract.java:262)
 at org.apache.isis.core.metamodel.facets.actions.action.invocation.ActionInvocationFacetForDomainEventAbstract$2.execute(ActionInvocationFacetForDomainEventAbstract.java:223)
 at org.apache.isis.applib.services.iactn.Interaction.executeInternal(Interaction.java:173)
 at org.apache.isis.applib.services.iactn.Interaction.execute(Interaction.java:143)
 at org.apache.isis.core.metamodel.facets.actions.action.invocation.ActionInvocationFacetForDomainEventAbstract.doInvoke(ActionInvocationFacetForDomainEventAbstract.java:311)
 at org.apache.isis.core.metamodel.facets.actions.action.invocation.ActionInvocationFacetForDomainEventAbstract$1.execute(ActionInvocationFacetForDomainEventAbstract.java:165)
 at org.apache.isis.core.runtime.system.transaction.IsisTransactionManager.executeWithinTransaction(IsisTransactionManager.java:143)
 at org.apache.isis.core.runtime.system.transaction.IsisTransactionManager.executeWithinTransaction(IsisTransactionManager.java:133)
 at org.apache.isis.core.runtime.services.persistsession.PersistenceSessionServiceInternalDefault.executeWithinTransaction(PersistenceSessionServiceInternalDefault.java:179)
 at org.apache.isis.core.metamodel.facets.actions.action.invocation.ActionInvocationFacetForDomainEventAbstract.invoke(ActionInvocationFacetForDomainEventAbstract.java:161)
 at org.apache.isis.core.metamodel.specloader.specimpl.ObjectActionDefault.executeInternal(ObjectActionDefault.java:398)
 at org.apache.isis.core.metamodel.specloader.specimpl.ObjectActionDefault.execute(ObjectActionDefault.java:387)
 at org.apache.isis.core.metamodel.specloader.specimpl.ObjectActionDefault.executeWithRuleChecking(ObjectActionDefault.java:368)
 at org.apache.isis.viewer.wicket.model.models.ActionModel.executeAction(ActionModel.java:483)
 at org.apache.isis.viewer.wicket.model.models.ActionModel.load(ActionModel.java:462)
 at org.apache.isis.viewer.wicket.model.models.ActionModel.load(ActionModel.java:80)
 at org.apache.wicket.model.LoadableDetachableModel.getObject(LoadableDetachableModel.java:124)
 at org.apache.isis.viewer.wicket.model.models.ActionModel.executeHandlingApplicationExceptions(ActionModel.java:568)
 at org.apache.isis.viewer.wicket.ui.components.actions.ActionPanel.executeActionOnTargetAndProcessResults(ActionPanel.java:255)
 at org.apache.isis.viewer.wicket.ui.components.actions.ActionPanel.executeAndProcessResults(ActionPanel.java:204)
 at org.apache.isis.viewer.wicket.ui.components.actions.ActionParametersFormPanel$ActionParameterForm$1.onSubmit(ActionParametersFormPanel.java:148)
 at org.apache.wicket.ajax.markup.html.form.AjaxButton$1.onSubmit(AjaxButton.java:108)
 at org.apache.wicket.ajax.form.AjaxFormSubmitBehavior$AjaxFormSubmitter.onSubmit(AjaxFormSubmitBehavior.java:215)
 at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.delegateSubmit(Form.java:1305)
 at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.process(Form.java:966)
 at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.onFormSubmitted(Form.java:788)
 at org.apache.wicket.ajax.form.AjaxFormSubmitBehavior.onEvent(AjaxFormSubmitBehavior.java:171)
 at org.apache.wicket.ajax.AjaxEventBehavior.respond(AjaxEventBehavior.java:146)
 at org.apache.wicket.ajax.AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior.onRequest(AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior.java:641)
 ... 49 more
```

HMTL:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org">
    <body>
        <wicket:panel>
            <div class="PageablePanel scalarNameAndValueComponentType">
                <div class="form-group" wicket:id="scalarIfRegular">
                    <label wicket:id="scalarName" class="scalarName control-label mandatory">[Label text]</label>
                    <span class="scalarValueWrapper">
                        <span class="uploadFile help-block">
                           <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="scalarValue" wicket:id="scalarValue" />
                        </span>
                    </span>

                    <label wicket:id="scalarName1" class="scalarName control-label mandatory">[Label text]</label>
                    <span class="scalarValueWrapper">
                        <span class="uploadFile help-block">
                           <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="scalarValue1" wicket:id="scalarValue1" />
                        </span>
                        <a wicket:id="scalarIfRegularClear" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"><span class="clearTitle">Clear</span></a>
                        <span wicket:id="feedback" class="help-block"></span>
                        <span wicket:id="associatedActionLinksBelow"></span>
                    </span>
                    <span wicket:id="associatedActionLinksRight"></span>
                </div>
                <span wicket:id="scalarIfCompact"> </span>
            </div>
        </wicket:panel>
    </body>
</html>
```

On `PageablePanelAbstract.java` which extends `ScalarPanelAbstract`, there are three methods that is being overridden:

- `addComponentForRegular();`
- `addComponentForCompact();`
- `addFormComponentBehavior();`

**PageablePanelAbstract.java**

```js
public abstract class PageablePanelAbstract<T extends NamedWithMimeType & Serializable> extends ScalarPanelAbstract {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PageablePanelAbstract.class);
    private static final String ID_SCALAR_IF_REGULAR = "scalarIfRegular";
    private static final String ID_SCALAR_IF_REGULAR_CLEAR = "scalarIfRegularClear";
    private static final String ID_SCALAR_NAME = "scalarName";
    private static final String ID_SCALAR_VALUE = "scalarValue";
    private static final String ID_SCALAR_IF_COMPACT = "scalarIfCompact";

    private static final String PAGE_SIZE = "Page Size";
    private static final String PAGE_NUMBER = "Page Number";
    private TextField<T> textField;
    private TextField<T> textField2;

    protected WebMarkupContainer scalarTypeContainer;

    public PageablePanelAbstract(String id, ScalarModel scalarModel) {
        super(id, scalarModel);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onInitialize() {
        super.onInitialize();

        scalarTypeContainer = new WebMarkupContainer(ID_SCALAR_IF_REGULAR);
        scalarTypeContainer.add(new CssClassAppender(getScalarPanelType()));
        addOrReplace(scalarTypeContainer);
    }

    @Override
    protected FormGroup addComponentForRegular() {

        textField = createTextField(ID_SCALAR_VALUE);
        textField.setLabel(Model.of(getModel().getName()));
        textField.setRequired(getModel().isRequired());

        textField2 = createTextField("scalarValue1");
        textField2.setLabel(Model.of(getModel().getName()));
        textField2.setRequired(getModel().isRequired());

        final FormGroup labelIfRegularTextField = new FormGroup(ID_SCALAR_IF_REGULAR, textField);
        labelIfRegularTextField.add(textField);
        labelIfRegularTextField.add(textField2);

        final Label scalarNameTextField = new Label(ID_SCALAR_NAME, PAGE_NUMBER);
        labelIfRegularTextField.add(scalarNameTextField);

        final Label scalarNameTextField1 = new Label("scalarName1", PAGE_SIZE);
        labelIfRegularTextField.add(scalarNameTextField1);

        // find the links...
        final List<LinkAndLabel> entityActions = EntityActionUtil.getEntityActionLinksForAssociation(this.scalarModel, getDeploymentCategory());

        addPositioningCssTo(labelIfRegularTextField, entityActions);

        addOrReplace(labelIfRegularTextField);
        addFeedbackOnlyTo(labelIfRegularTextField, textField);
        addEditPropertyTo(labelIfRegularTextField);

        // ... add entity links to panel (below and to right)
        addEntityActionLinksBelowAndRight(labelIfRegularTextField, entityActions);

        return labelIfRegularTextField;
    }

    @Override
    protected Component addComponentForCompact() {
        final MarkupContainer scalarIfCompact = new WebMarkupContainer(ID_SCALAR_IF_COMPACT);
        addOrReplace(scalarIfCompact);
        return scalarIfCompact;
    }

    @Override
    protected void addFormComponentBehavior(Behavior behavior) {
        textField.add(behavior);
    }

    protected void onBeforeRenderWhenViewMode() {
        updateRegularFormComponents(InputFieldVisibility.NOT_VISIBLE);
    }

    protected void onBeforeRenderWhenDisabled(final String disableReason) {
        updateRegularFormComponents(InputFieldVisibility.NOT_VISIBLE);
    }

    protected void onBeforeRenderWhenEnabled() {
        updateRegularFormComponents(InputFieldVisibility.VISIBLE);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private T getText(final ScalarModel model) {
        ObjectAdapter adapter = model.getObject();
        return adapter != null ? (T) adapter.getObject() : null;
    }

    private void updateRegularFormComponents(final InputFieldVisibility visibility) {
        MarkupContainer formComponent = (MarkupContainer) getComponentForRegular();
        formComponent.get(ID_SCALAR_VALUE).setVisible(visibility == InputFieldVisibility.VISIBLE);

        updateClearLink(visibility);

    }

    private void updateClearLink(InputFieldVisibility visibility) {
        final MarkupContainer formComponent = (MarkupContainer) getComponentForRegular();
        formComponent.setOutputMarkupId(true); // enable ajax link

        final AjaxLink<Void> ajaxLink = new AjaxLink<Void>(ID_SCALAR_IF_REGULAR_CLEAR) {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                setEnabled(false);
                ScalarModel model = PageablePanelAbstract.this.getModel();
                model.setObject(null);
                target.add(formComponent);
                // target.add(fileNameLabel);
            }
        };
        ajaxLink.setOutputMarkupId(true);
        formComponent.addOrReplace(ajaxLink);

        final T txt = getTextFromModel();
        formComponent.get(ID_SCALAR_IF_REGULAR_CLEAR).setVisible(txt != null && visibility == InputFieldVisibility.VISIBLE);
    }

    private T getTextFromModel() {
        return getText(getModel());
    }

    protected enum InputFieldVisibility {
        VISIBLE, NOT_VISIBLE
    }

    protected TextField<T> createTextField(final String componentId) {

        return new TextField<>(componentId, newTextFieldValueModel());
        // return (TextField) textField;
    }

    protected TextFieldValueModel<T> newTextFieldValueModel() {
        return new TextFieldValueModel<>(this);
    }

    protected abstract IModel<String> getScalarPanelType();
}
```

Any idea on which of these methods I could manipulate to get the value of the two textfields? Thanks.

Comment: Please show us the code of the new/non-working method. Isn't there another exception or at least "Caused by" of this one ?

Comment: @martin-g I've updated my question, hope it helps. Thanks.

Comment: Could you please share the source code of PageablePanelAbstract.java too ? `addComponentForRegular()` constructs the Wicket component tree for `edit` mode, `addComponentForCompact()` - for `view` mode.

Comment: @martin-g I've updated my post providing the code for **PageablePanelAbstract.java**, I'm really new to adding wicket and only has a vague idea on how this works. Thanks in advance for your help martin.

Comment: Can I ask, what is the user goal you are trying to support here?  I'm just wondering if there's a better way without implementing a custom component?  Or, if it's a legitimate and common use case, then maybe we should add in support into the framework directly.?